# Android Fragment API 26 " The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Tags: android, android-fragments

Anyone see when moving from API 25 to 26 and removing fragments yields " The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."  This is getting called deep inside of Android Classes and not classes I've created.  I've created a sample app and can not get this to fail, however on the legacy code I'm working on it fails every time when I call. (Frag A added, then Frag B replace, then pop).

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_frag, container, false);
```

in the onCreateView

the Logcat shows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4659)
```

**UPDATE**

So it appears it has something to do with

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
```

Commenting this out no longer yields the crash.

Comment: Usually you say "false", then the runtime knows it should not try to add the new View to the container at once (it will be added anyway as part of the Fragment functionality, so "true" will cause the attempt to add it a second time)

Comment: @0X0nosugar oops my bad.. container is set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears it has something to do with

transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);